# Pass cart items and add-on variations in url in Woocommerce using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to pass data from a shopping cart to an external shipping site. The code below currently passes the product ID and quantity by removing the default checkout button from the basket and replace it with a 'Proceed to Shipping' button with a custom URL that passes the data into the external checkout page. After redirection I have another plugin that reads the URL and adds the data in the URL to the cart on the shipping site where payment is handled - So far so good everything works.

Now I am having to pass product add-on data...

I am using the free version of `YITH WooCommerce Product Add-Ons & Extra Options` https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-product-add-ons/ to add the add-ons. The custom add-ons are store in `wp_yith_wapo_addons table` (although it isn't obvious for me what details/field names exactly need to be passed).

However, my main issues is how would I write into the below plugin the function to read the add-ons added to every product in the cart and pass it in the url. My current URL that does work is as follows: `https://www.example.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=1099&quantity=1`

Example details of the cart are as follows:

```
 Football shirt
 Base price:
 £25.99

 Size:
 16 (2-3yrs)

 FREE Shirt Name:
 Option:
 Messi

 Extras:
 Add matching socks (+£3.49)
 Add League patches to Arms (+£1.99)
```

PHP plugin code below:

```
<?php
            /**
             * Plugin Name: Custom Payment Gateway
             * Description: Custom payment gateway that redirects customers to our external shipping site for payment.
             * Version: 1.0.1
             * Author: Chris / ChatGPT
             * Author URI: https://example.com/
             * Text Domain: custom-payment-gateway
             * Domain Path: /languages
             */

            if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
                exit;
            }

            add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_custom_payment_gateway');
            function add_custom_payment_gateway($gateways) {
                $gateways[] = 'WC_Custom_Payment_Gateway';
                return $gateways;
            }

            add_action('plugins_loaded', 'init_custom_payment_gateway');
            function init_custom_payment_gateway() {
                class WC_Custom_Payment_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

                    public function __construct() {
                        $this->id = 'custom_payment_gateway';
                        $this->method_title = 'Custom Payment Gateway';
                        $this->method_description = 'Custom payment gateway for WooCommerce.';
                        $this->supports = array('products');

                        $this->init_form_fields();
                        $this->init_settings();

                        $this->title = $this->get_option('title');
                        $this->button_label = $this->get_option('button_label');
                        $this->button_url = $this->get_option('button_url');

                        add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
                        add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'replace_proceed_to_checkout_button'));
                    }

                    public function init_form_fields() {
                        $this->form_fields = array(
                            'enabled' => array(
                                'title' => __('Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce'),
                                'type' => 'checkbox',
                                'label' => __('Enable Custom Payment', 'woocommerce'),
                                'default' => 'no'
                            ),
                            'title' => array(
                                'title' => __('Title', 'woocommerce'),
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'description' => __('This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce'),
                                'default' => __('Custom Payment', 'woocommerce'),
                                'desc_tip' => true,
                            ),
                            'button_label' => array(
                                'title' => __('Button Label', 'woocommerce'),
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'description' => __('This controls the label of the button.', 'woocommerce'),
                                'default' => __('Go to External Site', 'woocommerce'),
                                'desc_tip' => true,
                            ),
                            'button_url' => array(
                                'title' => __('Button URL', 'woocommerce'),
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'description' => __('This is the URL of the external site.', 'woocommerce'),
                                'default' => '',
                                'desc_tip' => true,
                            ),
                        );
                    }

                    public function replace_proceed_to_checkout_button() {
                        if (is_cart()) {
                            global $woocommerce;

                            $checkout_url = esc_url($this->button_url);

                            // Get cart data
                            $cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

                            // Initialize arrays for product IDs and quantities
                            $product_ids = array();
                            $quantities = array();

                            // Loop through cart items and populate product IDs and quantities arrays
                            foreach ($cart_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
                                $product_ids[] = $cart_item['product_id'];
                                $quantities[] = $cart_item['quantity'];
                            }

                            // Determine the URL structure based on the number of items in the cart
                            if (count($cart_items) > 1) {
                                $query_params = array(
                                    'add-to-cart' => implode(',', $product_ids),
                                    'quantity' => implode(',', $quantities),
                                );
                            } else {
                                $query_params = array(
                                    'add-to-cart' => $product_ids[0],
                                    'quantity' => $quantities[0],
                                );
                            }

                            $checkout_url = add_query_arg($query_params, $checkout_url);

                            ?>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                jQuery(function($) {
                                    var checkout_url = "<?php echo $checkout_url; ?>";

                                    // Replace the button
                                    $('.wc-proceed-to-checkout a.checkout-button').attr('href', checkout_url).text('<?php echo esc_js($this->button_label); ?>');
                                });
                            </script>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Simply don't use this horrible and closed plugin, there are a lot of better alternatives. The best one is to code yourself product custom fields, as there are already tons of working related answers in Stack OverFlow. This way you will be able to get the data easily to be sent externally.

Comment: I managed to get the variations added to cart, my issue now is adding multiple items. i guess i'll need to set up a new question